# Spring batch FlatFileItemWriter write as csv from Object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am using Spring batch and have an ItemWriter as follows:

```
public class MyItemWriter implements ItemWriter<Fixing> {

    private final FlatFileItemWriter<Fixing> writer;
    private final FileSystemResource resource;

    public MyItemWriter () {
        this.writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        this.resource = new FileSystemResource("target/output-teste.txt");
    }


    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Fixing> items) throws Exception {

        this.writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(resource.getFile()));
        this.writer.setLineAggregator(new PassThroughLineAggregator<>());
        this.writer.afterPropertiesSet();
        this.writer.open(new ExecutionContext());
        this.writer.write(items);
    }

    @AfterWrite
    private void close() {
        this.writer.close();
    }
}
```

When I run my spring batch job, the items are written to file as:

```
Fixing{id='123456', source='TEST', startDate=null, endDate=null}
Fixing{id='1234567', source='TEST', startDate=null, endDate=null}
Fixing{id='1234568', source='TEST', startDate=null, endDate=null}
```

1/ How can I write just the data so that the values are comma separated and where it is null, it is not written. So the target file should look like this:

```
123456,TEST
1234567,TEST
1234568,TEST
```

2/ Secondly, I am having an issue where only when I exit spring boot application, I am able to see the file get created. What I would like is once it has processed all the items and written, the file to be available without closing the spring boot application.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple options to write the csv file. Regarding second question writer flush will solve the issue.

1. https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-batch/flatfileitemwriter-write-to-csv-file/

2. We prefer to use OpenCSV with spring batch as we are getting more speed and control on huge file example snippet is below

   ```
   class DocumentWriter implements ItemWriter<BaseDTO>, Closeable {

          private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StatementWriter.class);

          private  ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<Statement> strategy ;

          private static final String[] columns = new String[] { "csvcolumn1", "csvcolumn2", "csvcolumn3",

                                       "csvcolumn4", "csvcolumn5", "csvcolumn6", "csvcolumn7"};

          private BufferedWriter writer;
          private StatefulBeanToCsv<Statement> beanToCsv;
          public DocumentWriter() throws Exception {

                         strategy = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<Statement>();

                        strategy.setType(Statement.class);

                         strategy.setColumnMapping(columns);

                         filename = env.getProperty("globys.statement.cdf.path")+"-"+processCount+".dat";

                         File cdf = new File(filename);

                  if(cdf.exists()){

                      writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(filename), StandardCharsets.UTF_8,StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

                  }else{

                      writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(filename), StandardCharsets.UTF_8,StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);

                  }

                  beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<Statement>(writer).withQuotechar(CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)

                          .withMappingStrategy(strategy).withSeparator(',').build();

          }

          @Override

          public void write(List<? extends BaseDTO> items) throws Exception {

                         List<Statement> settlementList = new ArrayList<Statement>();

                         for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {

                                       BaseDTO baseDTO = items.get(i);

                                       settlementList.addAll(baseDTO.getStatementList());

                         }

                         beanToCsv.write(settlementList);

                         writer.flush();

          }

          @PreDestroy

          @Override

          public void close() throws IOException {

                         writer.close();

          }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using PassThroughLineAggregator which does item.toString() for writing the object, overriding the toString() function of classes extending Fixing.java should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

> 1/ How can I write just the data so that the values are comma separated and where it is null, it is not written.

You need to provide a custom `LineAggregator` that filters out `null` fields.

> 2/ Secondly, I am having an issue where only when I exit spring boot application, I am able to see the file get created

This is probably because you are calling `this.writer.open` in the `write` method which is not correct. You need to make your item writer implement `ItemStream` and call `this.writer.open` and this `this.writer.close` respectively in `ItemStream#open` and `ItemStream#close`

Comment: for 1/ I used a `NullSafeBeanWrapperFieldExtractor`. for 2/, I made the changes to implement ItemStream, but the issue was resolved before when I started using `@Configuration` on my writer, and previously it wasn't and I was creating the bean in my job configuration